# Run a script piped from stdin (Linux/Shell Scripting)

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command-line

Suppose I have a script: **my_script.sh**

Instead of doing

```
./my_script.sh
```

I want to do something like:

```
cat my_script.sh | <some command here>
```

such that the script executes. Is this possible?

The use case is if the script I want to execute is the output of a wget or s3cat, etc. Right now I save it to a temporary file, change it to executable, and then run it. Is there a way to do it directly?

Comment: You have to be very careful doing this. If anything inside of your script reads from stdin (for example, any command that prompts the user for "Yes/No"), it will consume lines *from your script*, and those lines will not get executed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just pipe it to your favorite shell, for example:

```
$ cat my_script.sh
set -x
echo hello
$ cat my_script.sh | sh
+ echo hello
hello
```

(The `set -x` makes the shell print out each statement it is about to run before it runs it, handy for debugging, but it has nothing to do with your issue specifically - just there for demo purposes.)

Comment: if the script specifies the shell type with the "#!" stuff, then does that override whatever shell I pipe it into?

Comment: No, that won't work, the shell you pipe to will interpret that as a comment (i.e. not at all). That's going to be tricky to do without a temp file. (Oh, and you do realize that this (wget'ing stuff and running it) is potentially really dangerous, right?)

Comment: Okay, thanks. And yes, agreed that it's dangerous if the file is not from a trusted source (though it's just as dangerous as automatically saving it to a file and then executing it).

Answer (score 6):

You could use stdin from pipe:

```
cat my_script.sh | xargs -i <some_command> {}
```

or:

```
cat my_script.sh | bash -
```

or (just from stdin):

```
bash < my_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

RVM recommends this method to [run their installer](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/):

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```